# Not seeing all blobs when using the Azure List Blobs Container API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to find a simple way to list log files which I am storing in and Azure Blob Container so developers and admins can easily get to dev log information. I am following the information in this API doc https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd135734.aspx but when I go to

```
https://-my-storage-url-.blob.core.windows.net/dev?comp=list&nclude={snapshots,metadata,uncommittedblobs,copy}&maxresults=1000
```

I see one file listed which is a Block Blob but the log files I have generated which are of type Append Blob are not showing. How can I construct this api call to include Append Blobs?

Comment: Can you trace your request/response in Fiddler? One thing you might want to check is the "x-ms-version" header in both request and response.

Comment: I am not setting any request headers, my goal is to just open this in a web-browser. The response headers coming back are: Content-Type → application/xml
Date → Tue, 26 Apr 2016 17:13:02 GMT
Server → Blob Service Version 1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Transfer-Encoding → chunked
x-ms-request-id → ae3ed574-0001-0133-4fde-9f3907000000

Comment: You need to set the x-ms-version to version 2015-02-21 and above, it will returns blobs of all types including append blob.

Comment: Thanks @forester123 that did resolve my problem but also means I cannot just give my admins a browser URL since I need to pass in that header :(. Thanks for the accurate answer though